# How to fetch and display data using AJAX on Navigation Click

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this client list page

[image]

when i click on that consult page it takes me to the client dashboard page

[image]

On that page i want to use Ajax to fetch data as a user clicks on the navigation, like if a user clicks demographics an Ajax call is made, and that person's demographics should be displayed.

here is the Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var pid = $("#id").val();

        function load_page_details(){

            $.ajax({
                url : "dashboard_data.php",
                method: "POST",
                data:{pid:pid},
                success: function(data) {

                    $("#client_info").html(data);
                }

            }); // ends ajax call

        } // ends load page details function



        $(".data li").click(function(){

            var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
            load_page_details(page_id);
        });
```

So on the dashboard_data.php i fetch records from different tables using the id provided on clicking the consult button, how do i make my application that when i click on demographics its show demographics data fetched from that table, also when clicking appointments it should show that information from the appointments table and so forth. Here is the navigation on the dashboard page

```
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked data">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#"><h4>Client Data</h4></a></li>

                                <li id="1"><a href="#"> Demographics </a></li>
                                <li id="2"><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
                                <li id="3"><a href="#">Vitals</a></li>
                                <li id="4"><a href="#">Work Out Plan</a></li>
                                <li id="5"><a href="#">Lipogram Results</a></li>
                                <li id="6"><a href="#">Diet Plan</a></li>

                     </div>
```

Comment: your code seems ok, what errors do you have?

Comment: use var pid = $("#id").val(); inside the load_page_details function.

Comment: @madalinivascu it has no errors, but the thing is it only shows the demographics even if i am clicking a different link

Comment: @BibekJana tried that it still does the same thing

Comment: @MorenaToxx see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Pass `pid` to your function,remove the global variable

```
function load_page_details(pid) {
```

Comment: Mind you the pid is a person's id posted to the dashboard form the home page, it is the one used to select that persons's data from different tables. Its not a navigation link id

Comment: so how are you passing the page_id  to the ajax?

Comment: what role does the ajax have?

Comment: the ajax was used to fetch client data correlating to that id..

thanks for your input, i was able to resolve it